# Simulate a matricies of data using R as bands of satellite imagery

Tags: r

The idea is to use a simple function to generate an image with 3 bands of Red Green and Blue imagery simulating multispectral imagery from satellite. So a composite of 3 different matricies (numerical scale of 0-255 (8 bit data)). And the 3 different matrices should be merged into a single matrix to visulaize a satellite imagery

Comment: Used the below code to generate a matrix but this code is used to create single matrix
#To generate a matrix of random numbers between 0 - 256.

x <- LETTERS[1:10]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,10))
data <- expand.grid(X=x, Y=y)
dum <- sample(1:256,100,replace=TRUE)
data$Z <- dum
mat <- matrix(dum,byrow = TRUE,nrow=10)
final=as.table(mat)
print(final)

#To get the heatmap

ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, fill= Z)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black",
            lwd = 0.5,
            linetype = 1) +
  coord_fixed()+scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Reds")

Comment: Add your code to your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.